# Subnet and internet connection

Tags: subnet

I have new public IP Address from a new ISP . I decided to assign the computers the subnet of 192.168.0.0/22. What else do you need to do to allow these computers to access the Internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the router is in the same subnet and that the router is set up to forward packets and do NAT.

You would commonly set the router up to do DHCP to hand IP addresses, netmask and gateway -  and DNS addresses to each computer from a range in the subnet.  Otherwise you would hard code these. on each device.